# How can I stop slider moved by mouse wheel at the last image?

Tags: javascript, slider, mousewheel, getboundingclientrect

I am working on a multi-image slider (i.e. several images appear next to each other at the same time and move together) that can be moved with the mouse wheel. I detect the direction of the mouse wheel (up or down) and the slider moves to the left or the right accordingly. It works quite well, the only problem is that I can't get the last picture to stop at the edge of the slider, so it doesn't jump inside if you roll a bigger with the mouse wheel (same for the first picture if you scroll backwards). I would be really grateful for some assistance. Thank you in advance. This is my JS code:

```
  // move slider on mouse wheel scrolling depending on mouse wheel direction
  aboutSliders[i].addEventListener('wheel', () => {
    // let slideWidth = firstImg.getBoundingClientRect().width;

    // get the first slide's position from left side of screen
    let sliderLeft = firstImg.getBoundingClientRect().left;
       // get the slider wrapper's position from left side of screen
    
    let sliderWrapperLeft = aboutSliders[i].getBoundingClientRect().left;

        // get the last slide's position from left side of screen
    let sliderRight = lastImg.getBoundingClientRect().right;
      // get the slider wrapper's position from left side of screen
    let sliderWrapperRight = aboutSliders[i].getBoundingClientRect().right;

    // detect mouse wheel's direction (up or down) 
    function detectMouseWheelDirection(e) {
      var delta = null,
        direction = false;
      if (!e) {
        // if the event is not provided, we get it from the window object
        e = window.event;
      }
      if (e.wheelDelta) {
        // will work in most cases
        delta = e.wheelDelta / 60;
      } else if (e.detail) {
        // fallback for Firefox
        delta = -e.detail / 2;
      }
      if (delta !== null) {
        direction = delta > 0 ? 'up' : 'down';
      }

      return direction;
    }

    
    function handleMouseWheelDirection(direction) {
      // if mousewheel direction is 'down' and the slider wrapper's position is not further to the right than the last slide's, move the slider to the left
      if (direction == 'down' && sliderRight >= sliderWrapperRight) {
        innerSlider.style.marginLeft = --count * 5 + '%';

        // if mousewheel direction is 'up', and the slider wrapper's position is not further to the left than the first slide's, move the slider to the right
      } else if (direction == 'up' && sliderLeft <= sliderWrapperLeft) {
        innerSlider.style.marginLeft = ++count * 5 + '%';
      }
    }

    document.onmousewheel = function (e) {
      handleMouseWheelDirection(detectMouseWheelDirection(e));
    };

    if (window.addEventListener) {
      document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', function (e) {
        handleMouseWheelDirection(detectMouseWheelDirection(e));
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: so the photos are available and when you scroll, the pictures together move to the left and right ?

Comment: It feels weird to have handlers "onmousewheel / DOMMouseScroll" set inside another handler ("wheel") IMO you should simplify it and set only one handler depending on the browser support (mostly to ensure that multiple handlers are not run concurrently on the same element). My instinct would tell me that your problem is `sliderLeft` and `sliderRight` values are not updated in the inner handlers, can you run it with a console.log to confirm?

Comment: Yes, you may be right! Thank you for clarifying it. I solved the problem meanwhile. Simply if the sliderRight becomes smaller than sliderWrapperRight, I roll the whole slider back to the start, that is, I give a value of 0 to the 'left' property.